# Fortran header file contains COMMON /sth/sth2(param1,param2,param3)

Tags: fortran90

I've to translate a Fortran program into C++ and the Fortran program INCLUDEs a header file containing many lines like the one below : 


    `COMMON/TDD/IDONE(NX,NY,NZ),IDTWO(NX,NY,NZ),IDTHRE(NX,NY,NZ)

    COMMON/ESCAT/EXS(NX,NY,NZ),EYS(NX,NY,NZ),EZS(NX,NY,NZ)

    COMMON/HSCAT/HXS(NX,NY,NZ),HYS(NX,NY,NZ),HZS(NX,NY,NZ)`


Here NX, NY and NZ are integers
I have no idea what these lines do

Comment: One possible translation is to convert them to a global nameless struct/class. eg struct{int idOne[NX][NY][NZ]; int idTwo[NX][NY][NZ]; int idThre[NX][NY][NZ];} tdd;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those lines each declare a common block, a now old-fashioned and deprecated approach to sharing variables between compilation units (or scopes) in a Fortran program.

To take the first one as an example, the line

```
COMMON/TDD/IDONE(NX,NY,NZ),IDTWO(NX,NY,NZ),IDTHRE(NX,NY,NZ)
```

declares a named common block called `TDD` which groups the variables listed on the rest of the line.  Given that `NX`, `NY` and `NZ` are integers, `IDONE`, `IDTWO`, and `IDTHRE` are all rank-3 arrays.

All the compilation units which include the line(s) defining a common block have access to both the common block and the variables named in it.  You might wonder why the variable names have to be listed whenever the common block is included in a compilation unit.  That's because it is legal to rename variables in a common block so that the same variable has one name in one scope and another name in another scope.  You might want to be on the look out for a line such as

```
COMMON/TDD/ENODI(NX,NY,NZ),IDTWO(NX,NY,NZ),IDTHRE(NX,NY,NZ)
```

which means that the variable called `IDONE` in one scope is called `ENODI` in another.

Even more fun, it's possible to use common blocks to redefine variables entirely.  Imagine a common block declaration such as

```
COMMON/BADEX/X,Y,Z
```

where `X` ,`Y`, and `Z` are all reals, then the (re-)declaration

```
COMMON/BADEX/CMPL,Z
```

where `CMPL` is declared as a complex variable, allows you to identify the real and imaginary components of `CMPL` with `X` and `Y`.

One of the reasons that common blocks are now deprecated is because they dictate to the compiler the layout of the variables in memory, essentially that the variables in the common block should be laid out adjacent to one another in the order specified.  It is this *storage association* which supports renaming and redeclaring variables through the use of common blocks.